# How to draw lines with angle and distance in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, draw

I am having an app in which I am doing some calculations and based on that I want to draw a traverse like shown below.

Here is an image of the traverse.

[image: Traverse Image]

I have distance of AB, BC and so on.

Based on this values I need to draw an image shown above.

I know how to draw a line using UIBezierPath and using the below code.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
```

But how to draw this with this calculations. I am confused with it. I just want some guidance on it.

My main aim is to draw image with the design pattern shown below.

**EDIT**

I have a distance of 50.0 and an angle of 37 for line AB. How to draw a line AB from that?

Please help.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Example:

```
 - (void)drawTraverseWithFirstPoint:(CGPoint)firstPoint secondPoint:(CGPoint)point thirdPoint:(CGPoint)thirdPoint fourthPoint:(CGPoint)fourthPoint andLastPoint:(CGPointLastPoint) {

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:your_start_point];
    [path addLineToPoint:firstPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:secondPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:thirdPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:fourthPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:lastPoint];


    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
}
```

Just do the calculations first and pass it as paramethers or pass an Array with points however it is easier for you, i hope you will understand my example good day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got this but what I want to get is I have only angle and distance for line AB. Then from that how to find start point and end points so that I can pass the values in bazier path?

Comment: Well you must define a start_point,  for example `CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(20,self.frame.size.height / 2);` 
Your startPoint is a constant that must fit with all screen's devices that your system will work.

Now for the formula, i don't know how you calculate the whole shape... so i cant help, my idea was that you have a whole calculation done and then you draw it on screen, if you want you can write the formula you use. Regards

Comment: Ok Thanks. Do you know how to draw a line to an angle? I have length and angle of a line. +1 for giving me the idea.